# Cannot remove "select" UI in React on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, drop-down-menu

This is a very weird behavior - please refer to this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qyc3e774/

The goal is that when the select does an "onChange" event, the `select` is removed. However an unexpected thing occurs in mobile.

When you select a value, the select is replaced by a standard button that does nothing. But once you tap on the button, the browser brings up the select menu again even though there is no `select` element there. If you look into the DOM, there is no select element.

Why is this occurring and how can I fix this?

Code:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {show: true}
  },
  onChange: function() {
    this.setState({show: false})
  },
  render: function() {  
    if(this.state.show) {
      return (<select onChange={this.onChange}>
        <option value="1">value1</option>
        <option value="2">value2</option>
      </select>);
    }else {
        return <button type="button">this should do nothing</button>
    }

  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Possible solutions:
1) Add css rule for display: none instead of removing the select seems to work. This is not ideal though... Would prefer to remove the element if I can.

Comment: Real mobile device. I tested this on my iphone 6S on mobile chrome and mobile safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is because the `select` is still focused even after removal. Need to blur it when it gets removed.